# 404 not found after creating new website Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I created new website and new store. I added URL and Designer. After that I wrote in my .htaccess

> ```
> SetEnvIf Host usatravelshop\.loc MAGE_RUN_CODE=chny
> SetEnvIf Host usatravelshop\.loc MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
> SetEnvIf Host www\.dev\.usatravelshop\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=usatravelshop
> SetEnvIf Host www\.dev\.usatravelshop\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
> ```

but when I have tried come to my URL, I have 404.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code bellow in your `index.php` right before `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'domain1.com':
    case 'www.domain1.com':
        $mageRunCode = 'domain1_com';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
    break;
    case 'domain2.com':
    case 'www.domain2.com':
        $mageRunCode = 'domain2_com';
       $mageRunType = 'website';
    break;
}
```

**nb:** don't forget to point your new url of the second domaine in your vhost

Comment: before `Mage::run` i have 
`/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';`
i should delete it?

Comment: I got u, but i don't want, that my first store is enabled( may be it's need more settings, that URL and style?

Comment: And my `$mageRunType` and `$mageRunCode` are `website` and `my type`

Comment: I didn't understand what you told me, did you tried my solution ?

Comment: i change `store` instead `website` and it worked))

Comment: Yes, of course, i gave you an exemple and you can replace the website with store. if that helped you, please accept the answer

Comment: may be u know where is situated in database my style of the website?

Comment: `core_config_data` I think !